# how can i copy html breadcrumb in visual code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

is there a way to copy HTML breadcrumb as CSS selectors or at least as space-separated elements-selectors?
[image]

Comment: This is an old thread, but did you find a solution for this?
Is it possible to create an extension for this matter? If so, is there any guide that could help me creating one?

Comment: @CleberGriff I do not remember I found a solution for it, but I think you can build an extension, you can check vscode official documentation on how to build an extension

Comment: Thanks Ahmad! Sorry for "resurrecting" this old thread guys! I will let you know if I code anything that can help us with this matter :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a feature that has not yet been implemented. However [someone submitted an issues for this a couple of years ago](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/58678). It was placed on the backlog a couple of months ago. Hopefully they'll get to it sooner rather than later.

PS this probably belongs in the comment section but I still don't have enough reputation to post there yet so I figured I would just put it here.